# Parsing domain from Slack message

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack

What is the best way to parse the domain from a Slack message? I have a Slack bot that is used to perform lookups on any hostname that is provided. When the bot receives the payload from Slack the domain is in this format: `<http://example.com|example.com>`. For this application I simply need `example.com`.

One method to parse this would be to split the string using the '|' character and removing the "< >" characters and simply use the 2nd element.

```
msg = slack_response
strip1 = msg.replace(">", "")
strip2 = strip1.replace("<", "")

str_arr = strip2.split("|")

domain = str_arr[1]
```

Are there any better methods/libraries that can be used to parse the domain out? The bot will not always receive a domain and it can sometimes be in the form of an IP as well such as `8.8.8.8`. I would prefer to perform this in a way that can deal for both scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex but since the response from slack is predictable I think it's probably overkill.

If you wanted a one liner you could do

```
msg.split("|")[-1][:-1]
```

However, because readability counts I would recommend something like

```
start = msg.find("|") + 1
stop = msg.find{">")
domain = msg[start:stop]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
msg.replace('>', '').split('|')[1]
```